# Windows Server 2003 Standby/Sleep Results in Cold Boot when Resuming

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm running Windows Server 2003 sp2 on a Dell Inspiron e1705. There has never been a problem going to standby/sleep mode (by closing the laptop lid, or from the Start menu), and then resuming later.

Today I did a Windows Update to install the latest patches and fixes. I don't know if there is a correlation, but now when I resume from standby/sleep mode, the machine does a cold boot.

The AC adapter is connected. The battery is 2 months old, and all its LEDs light up when pressing its test button. The Power Management shows it at "99% (charging)" all the time.

There is nothing suspicious in any of the event logs.

Any ideas?